# gradle ear plugin - custom jar's added to EAR root folder

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, ear

I am trying to build ear using gradle build and ear is building fine.In my project ejb module is creating multiple custom jar along with ejb jar .How to add them onto ear root directory instead of adding them in lib folder

I am able to include them in ear lib folder but not in EAR root directory

EAR/APP-INF/lib/A.jar
should be EAR/A.jar

```
project(':A-project')
earproject(path: ':A-project',configurations:'provided')
earfiles(project(':A-project').tasks.findByName('ATask'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies
{
deploy project(path: ':A-Project')//jar files
deploy project(path: ':B-Project',configuration:'archives')//war files
deploy project(project(':C-Project').tasks.findByName("app"))//project in built jars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `deploy(A.jar)` to your `dependencies{}` code block. This will create an `ejb` entry in the `application.xml`

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   deploy(A.jar)
}
```

[Reference](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-ear-plugin-includes-the-project-jar-itself-on-an-earlib-dependency/3999)